# Is the plural better in "help the weak(s)"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nominal-adjectives

[image: the composition]

There is a sentence: *Monkey king uses a magic stick to fight bad people and help the weak.*

As you can see, the author used *the weak* in the third line from the end of the composition above.

My question is:
Would it be better if the phrase be replaced with the plural form *the weaks* for a correspondence with the previous phrase *the people*?

Comment: Nice handwriting. Yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... to fight bad people and help **the weak**.

**No, "the weak" is grammatically correct.**

*weak* is an adjective, not a noun. It needs a noun to modify; in this construction the noun is *people* but it turns out you can actually hide the noun and just use the adjective as if it were the noun itself, to mean "everyone who is described by this adjective." This is probably used most famously in Matthew 5:5:

> Blessed are **the meek**, for they shall inherit the Earth.

In English adjectives that do not relate to number are always singular—they do not agree with the count of the noun they modify. We say "the green apple" *and* "the green apple**s**," "the weak person" *and* "the weak people."

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, is "the weaks" grammatically wrong?

Comment: @TeaNut yes, there *is no word* "weaks" in English and so it would be incorrect to use it.

Answer (score 2):

> Monkey king uses a magic stick to fight bad people and help the weak.

*the weak* is defined in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20weak) as

> noun

> weak people

> the weak and the powerful

*weak* is a nominalized adjective, as described in [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective)

> A nominalized adjective is an adjective that has undergone nominalization, and is thus used as a noun. In the rich and the poor, the adjectives rich and poor function as nouns denoting people who are rich and poor respectively.

> Many adjectives, though, have undergone conversion so that they can be used regularly as countable nouns; examples include Catholic, Protestant, red (with various meanings), green, etc.

*weak* has not undergone this conversion as countable nouns.